# Is it possible to have two databases sharing the same files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication, redundancy

I'm designing one application and considering some options regarding the database system since i'm not familiar with Microsoft sql server.

I would like to know if its possible to have 2 databases sharing the same files, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtU2F.png

The idea is that the data is in a raid system so it would grant us some safety and this way we would save effort in synchronizing both databases, and save some money in storage equipment.

Also we only need one DB at a time, the secondary one is just for use in case of failure of the first one.

Is this possible? (I'm also open to different approaches, the main problem is just the database redundancy, our application must guarantee that)

Comment: I highly doubt it - you'd be basically trying to have the equivalent of one single HD/partition acting as the C: for two seperate boxes. They're going to be stomping on each other left/right/center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat possible. You have a few options. You can do SQL Server clustering which requires a SAN and shares the data file between the 2 instances, or a more economic approach is SQL mirroring.

Clustering has 2 options Active/Active or Active/Passive where as MIrroing is always Active/Passive. SQL Clustering on anything but a highly performant SAN will no doubt cause performance problems in SQL.

Both solutions have automatic failover and based on your needs, I would recommend Mirroring as a good solution.

A good summary of all your options is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx):

Comment: can I do the SQL Server clustering in just one machine sharing the same hard drive in order to not having to use a SAN     ?